# How to use a filter in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Shop ID</th>
            <th>Total Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="order_item in orderitemList | orderBy: 'id'">
                <td ng-bind="order_item.id"></td>
                <td ng-bind="order_item.shop_id"></td>
                <td ng-bind="order_item.total_price"></td>
                <td>{{order_item.date | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
                <td ng-bind="order_item.status"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

I tried to use |my filter function but it didn't work, so I think there is some another way to replace order item status to other meanings. In database status datatype is "bigint", and I want to show meanings with datatype string! Sincerely, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom pipe ([how-to](https://medium.com/@pankaj.itdeveloper/how-to-create-custom-pipes-in-angular-5b831463636c)), then in the `transform()` method you do your magic with your bigInt`*(maybe a string switch?)* and return the value

[Another example of custom pipes!](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-pipes-custom-pipes)